# Using include and orderby is throwing Null exception in dotnet 2.x version

Tags: .net-core, ef-core-2.0, ef-core-2.1

The following code worked in dotnet core 1.x version. But after upgrading the project to 2.x version the same logic is throwing `NullReferenceException : Object reference not set to an instance of an object.`.

```
return DbSet.Include(x => x.PersonnelRoles)
                        .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
                                .Where(filter)
                                .OrderBy(x => x.FullNameLF)
                                .ToList();
```

Comment: Share the exception details please!

Comment: @Tanvir The code works fine in dotnet core 1.x. But the problem was when I upgraded the project to donet core 2.x. The code works fine if I remove the orderby().

Comment: Can you give team viewer id and pass to check where the problem actually lies as your shared code is fine.

Comment: I am facing this issue in my work project so won't be able to use team viewer.

Comment: @Oh! no option to access your computer remotely?

Comment: Through my research I found that there have been some issues when upgrading the dotnet framework.
 The workaround we did was to use ToList() before OrderBy() which fixed the issue. But I am trying to find the right 
way to fix this. 
`return DbSet.Include(x => x.PersonnelRoles)
  .ThenInclude(x => x.Role)
  .Where(filter)
  .ToList() //WORKAROUND - To be fixed.
  .OrderBy(x => x.FullNameLF)
  .ToList();`

Comment: It would have been better if I had the opportunity see your project configuration.